# PrimeFaces 5.2 selectCheckboxMenu not support Map<String,String> style selectItems

Tags: primefaces, mapping, jsf-2.2, keyvaluepair, selectcheckboxmenu

I am trying to use

```
Map<String,String>
```

style selectItems in my

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

but unfortunately, it not works.

Backing bean:

```
@Named(value = "roleBean")
@SessionScoped
public class RoleBean(){
  private Map<String,String> roleMap;
  private String[] selectRoles;
  ......
  ......
  public void findRoleMap(){
    if(roles.size()>0){
      for(Role r:roles){
        roleMap.put(r.getRoleId(),r.getRoleName());
      }
    logger.info("Role Map size: " + roleMap.size());
    }
  }
}
```

jsf as:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="roles" value="#{roleBean.selectRoles}" label="Select your roles" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" height="200" panelStyle="width:200px">
   <f:selectItems value="#{roleBean.roleMap.entrySet}" var="entry" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" itemValue="#{entry.key}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

When I access the page, I found there is 6 records were added into the map. but unfortunately, there is nothing shows up in the selectCheckboxMenu drop down list.

If I change the UIComponent to

```
<p:selectOneMenu>
```

from

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

it shows up properly in dropdown list.

I tried to find out through google, I didn't find anyone else trying to use key/value pair in Map style as selectItems in selectCheckboxMenu. I was very confused.

My question is: Does selectCheckboxMenu support key/value pair mapping style or not, if it does. How To do it?

Please advise!!

Comment: _"Please advise!!"_ Try 5.3 or 6.0 first. Regarding 'supporting it', you can check the source (it is open) And did you try `Map<String, Boolean>`?

Comment: Thank you for you advice. Unfortunately. I am using webLogic 12cR2, it only support JSF 2.2 and primeFaces 5.2. Other version primeFaces not tested. Maybe will have some unknown error.

Comment: Uhhh... Weblogic 12cR2 should run PrimeFaces 5.3 or 6.0 as well. No reason it should not

Answer (score 0):

```xhtml
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.map.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
    itemLabel="#{entry.key}" itemValue="#{entry.value}" />
```